# A grammatic question about modification

Tags: grammaticality, determiners

Why can we say "a not very intelligent boy", but not "a not intelligent boy"?

Comment: Because "not" modifies "very", so if you drop "very" "not" is left 'hanging' because it cannot here modify "intelligent".

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But why can't "not" modify "intelligent" here?

Comment: Because, in general, attributive adjectives cannot be negated directly by "not". Note, though, that "not"  is permitted where the adjective consists of a base preceded by a negative prefix, as in "He is a not unintelligent boy".

Comment: @BillJ: We don't generally use them, probably because there's usually a better way of saying it (like *unintelligent*). But are they ungrammatical? I don't believe so. I can find *a not great offer*, *a not great distance*, *a not great day,* etc. on the web. And this is probably because there's no one-word negation of *great*: *ungreat, ingreat, non-great* don't exist, or are very uncommon.

Comment: @Peter Shor Let's go with '90% unacceptable' then. 9 out of 10 English teachers would mark it wrong. The 'grammatical or not?' debate will no doubt settle down sometime.

Answer (score 0):

You question seems that you wonder why "not" can't modify intelligent.

"not" is an adverb which likes verbs such as
is/are/was/were/have/has/must/can/could/shall/should/will/would/may/might/do/does/did

"not" is combined with these verbs to form a negative meaning.
(is not, was not, have not..., etc.)

"not" also comes after some verbs like "hope", "believe", for example, "I hope not" or "I believe not" when you reply to someone's question like "Is the man coming?"

If you make a negative meaning with "a not intelligent boy", you could use prefix "non" which has a negative meaning: a nonintelligent boy or a non-intelligent boy

British English likes using -(hyphen) more than American English does.

For your grammar, as you can see "He is not an intelligent boy", "He isn't an intelligent boy", "He isn't a very intelligent boy", if "not" is used in a sentence, it becomes a linking verb which needs complements such as a noun, adjective and the word order is like this: a/an/the+(very)+adjective+noun or just a single noun with an appropriate indefinite article of "a" or "an", or definite article "the"

For your info.

He is intelligent (O)

He is not intelligent (O)

He isn't intelligent (O)

He is intelligent boy (X)

He is not intelligent boy (X)

He is not an intelligent boy (O)

He is a not intelligent boy (X) > "a" isolated "not" from "is" (**divorced**)

Now "not" does not function as a verbal negation and can't directly modify attributive adjective like "intelligent" in an example you gave.

So, "a not intelligent boy" is no good(grammatically wrong).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I understand what you mean by explaining how "not" should be used. But I'm still wondering: can "not" modify the adjective "intelligent"? It seems that it can, for we have sentences like "he is not intelligent", but why can't it be used here? :)

Comment: @Erato  Because, in general, attributive adjectives cannot be negated directly by "not". Note, though, that "not" is permitted where the adjective consists of a base preceded by a negative prefix, as in "He is a not unintelligent boy".

Comment: @Brandon In the OP's example "not" is a marker of non-verbal negation, so your references to the verb "be" are not relevant.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Now I can understand the rules: 1. generally, "not" cannot negate attributive adjectives directly, but it can when: a) the adjective consists of a base preceded by a negative prefix; b) the adjective doesn't have a proper one-word negation. 2. if we want "not" to function as a verbal negation, it must be right after the auxiliary. Is my conclusion correct here?

Comment: @Erato Not quite: if the adjective doesn't have a negative prefix, then it can't be negated. Instead, we have to find an alternative construction, so the ungrammatical *"He is a not nice person" would be recast as "He is not a nice person". Simple as that! You're right about verbal negation. It is marked either by negative inflection on the verb, as in "Ed **isn't** a very intelligent boy" or by modification on the verb by the separate word "not", as in "Ed is **not** a very intelligent boy". Does that help?

Comment: Yes!! Thank you very much :)